# Vector to matrix with row sum 1

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

I have a logical 1-by-n vector with sum m. Now, I need to convert it into a matrix m-by-n in a way that the row sum is equal 1.

```
vector (1-by-8) with sum 4
[0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1]

matrix (4-by-8) with row sum 1
[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0;
 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0;
 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0;
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
```

Is there a mathematically efficient way without calculating the sum, creating a empty matrix, loop through the vector and adding the 1s row by row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that in that case, given your input, you don't even need to calculate the sum. 
You can define an identity matrix of size *n*, then use your input vector to sample the required rows out of it:

```
I = eye(n);
y = I(x, :) ; % Output Matrix. x is the input vector
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method, using [`sparse`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html):

```
matrix = full(sparse(1:m, find(vector), 1, m, n));
```